# ngModel time validation

Tags: angular, angular-material, timepicker

I changed from

```
<input matInput type="time" [(ngModel)]="time" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

To:

```
<input matInput type="text" pattern="([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}"
   [(ngModel)]="time" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Which is the easiest way to add pattern error, without using FormBuilder, something similar with:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('time').errors?.pattern"> pattern error</mat-error>
```

Or any idea for some timepicker in 0-24 format?

Comment: Since you're using Angular material you can use the date input they provide, way easier that using a simple input. Ref: [datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), you can also use custom date formatters(such as moment)

Comment: @Nick any example?

Comment: I'm not trying to escape the question but you have literally tens of examples in the official docs under 'examples'. That's why i haven't posted an answer, i'm using the datepicker on a project and i think their explanation is very complete. Check it out and try to understand it, if you won't, edit your question posting your attempts and i'll help you further, but i'm sure it won't be necessary

Comment: I want to use timepicker, not datepicker. 
Otherwise, the main question is how to indicate pattern error without FormBuilder.

Comment: The material datepicker has support for datetime which allows you to pick time along with dates, that's all you can do about it, material doesn't have a timepicker component. If you want a timepicker you should build your own material-like component